# How to Import excel file in Mongo DB compass. Facing Error like key PK must not contain null bytes inmongo db compass

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have tried importing a excel file using mongoDB compass. Using Import and selecting CSV file in mongo db compass but Its not successfully importing showing following error.key **PK must not contain null bytes in mongo db compass**. If i try using other option like delimiter and tried all but using space its importing but all records in collection is like encoded something like this..**"   3 ' H ? W3    c޺8 ** How to import the excel file.

Please help with this thing.

Comment: Would you show a portion of the file you want to import?